# Validation error while trying to parse a json array to List[Object] in Scala

Tags: arrays, json, scala, playframework

I have a method that returns a JsArray of a type Foo.

To process the response, I am doing the following:

```
val foos : List[Foo] = Json.toJson(result).as[List[Foo]]
```

While debugging, I could see that the result is comming as:

```
"[]"
```

and it is generated by the code:

```
Ok(Json.toJson(foos))
```

Where **foos** is a **List[Foo]**

But I am getting the error:

> [JsResultException: JsResultException(errors:List((,List(ValidationError(error.expected.jsarray,WrappedArray())))))]

I've tried many ways, but can't solve this.

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: What does result look like? Also, Object is Java, while the equivalent in Scala is AnyRef.

Comment: as Object I mean Foo.

Comment: and the result of the method is "[]", since it is an empty List

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're most likely looking for `Json.parse`, rather than `Json.toJson`.

```
import play.api.libs.json.Json

scala> Json.toJson("[]")
res0: play.api.libs.json.JsValue = "[]"

scala> Json.parse("[]")
res1: play.api.libs.json.JsValue = []
```

Trying to convert `res0` to a `List[Foo]` doesn't work because you're trying to convert the string `"[]"` rather than than the same string without quotation marks, `[]`.

Answer (score 4):

It seems like you have it the wrong way around. `Json.toJson(value)` is used to convert from a Scala object to a JSON value. You are using it incorrectly to try and read a JSON body and convert it to a Scala object. You probably want to do something like this:

```
val foos : JsResult[List[Foo]] = result.validate[List[Foo]]
```

where result is your JSON value.

Look at this, under the 'JsValue to a model' section:

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaJson